# How to get more values from pandas .loc series without Index, Name and dtype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am creating function that returns value of columns of pandas dataframe depending on input conditions.

I am using df.loc to append my list of results but I want my list only to contain the names of Pokemons I need to get instead of the Index, value of column Name, Name of the column and data type of the object.

Here below is my code:

```
def get_best (move,type_poke,stat):
    max_stat=int()
    name=[]
    df =pd.read_csv('get_best.csv')
    if type_poke!='all' and move!='all':
        max_stat = df[df['type'].str.contains(type_poke) & df['move'].str.contains(move)][stat].max()
        name.append(df.loc[(df[stat] == max_stat)&(df['type'].str.contains(type_poke, na=False))&(df['move'].str.contains)(move, na=False), 'name'])
        print(name)
    elif type_poke=='all' and move!='all':
        max_stat = df[df['move'].str.contains(move, na=False)][stat].max()
        name.append(df.loc[(df[stat] == max_stat)&(df['move'].str.contains(move, na=False)), 'name'])
        print(name)
    elif type_poke!='all' and move=='all':
        max_stat = df[df['type'].str.contains(type_poke)][stat].max()
        name.append(df.loc[(df[stat] == max_stat)&(df['type'].str.contains(type_poke, na=False)), 'name'])
        print(name)
    else:
        max_stat = df[stat].max()
        name.append(df.loc[(df[stat] == max_stat), 'name'])
        print(name)

get_best('all', 'all', 'hp')
get_best('cut', 'rock', 'attack' )
get_best('all', 'ice', 'speed') 
get_best('laser-focus', 'all', 'hp')
get_best('light-screen', 'rock', 'special_attack') 
get_best('mega-kick', 'water', 'special_defense')
get_best('cut', 'grass', 'hp')
```

And this is output I get:

```
Name: name, dtype: object]
[408    rampardos
Name: name, dtype: object]
[460    weavile
Name: name, dtype: object]
[149    mewtwo
Name: name, dtype: object]
[792    nihilego
Name: name, dtype: object]
[198    slowking
Name: name, dtype: object]
[250       celebi
464    tangrowth
Name: name, dtype: object]
```

I want my output to be like this:

```
[blissey]

[rampardos]

[weavile]

[mewtwo]

[nihilego]

[slowking]

[celebi tangrowth]
```

Does anyone have any ideas?
Anything would help.
Sorry if I didn't format something right in the question.

Also this is CSV I use for my script:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsHhsH29mtf2rV94NkcmGSUE5wgT?e=zuMkfb

Comment: whatever you do with pandas dataframe, the return is usually a datagram (or pandas series), you need to use `.values` at the end of your query (where you use `.loc`) on the dataframe.

Comment: @AhmedElashry hello, I tried your suggestion but I still get [array(['celebi', 'tangrowth'], dtype=object)] dtype=object text which is not asked for.

Comment: sorry, I did not notice that you want them in list format. You can use `to_list()` instead. This is a Series method and since you are extracting one column at a time, you can use it.

Comment: @AhmedElashry thanks that worked you are a life savior. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Add `.iloc[0]` to the end of your row selections:

```
def get_best (move,type_poke,stat):
    max_stat=int()
    name=[]
    df =pd.read_csv('get_best.csv')
    if type_poke!='all' and move!='all':
        max_stat = df[df['type'].str.contains(type_poke) & df['move'].str.contains(move)][stat].max()
        name.append(df.loc[(df[stat] == max_stat)&(df['type'].str.contains(type_poke, na=False))&(df['move'].str.contains)(move, na=False), 'name'].iloc[0])
        print(name)
    elif type_poke=='all' and move!='all':
        max_stat = df[df['move'].str.contains(move, na=False)][stat].max()
        name.append(df.loc[(df[stat] == max_stat)&(df['move'].str.contains(move, na=False)), 'name'].iloc[0])
        print(name)
    elif type_poke!='all' and move=='all':
        max_stat = df[df['type'].str.contains(type_poke)][stat].max()
        name.append(df.loc[(df[stat] == max_stat)&(df['type'].str.contains(type_poke, na=False)), 'name'].iloc[0])
        print(name)
    else:
        max_stat = df[stat].max()
        name.append(df.loc[(df[stat] == max_stat), 'name'].iloc[0])
        print(name)
```